# A breakdown of what these functions do in this list?

Tags: python, list, func

A basic program that intends to generate a new list containing the elements of `list2`. Followed by the elements of `list1` in reverse order I can't seem to understand what the commented line means.

```
 def combine_lists(list1, list2):
      new_list = list2
      for i in reversed(range(len(list1))):   #this one
        new_list.append(list1[i])
      return new_list
    
    Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
    Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]
```

Comment: `reversed(range(len(list1)))` is a horrible way to write python code. Print the values of `i` inside the loop and you'll understand what it does. Use the same code without `reversed` and print the same.

Comment: To debug and understand a code, print the values and you'll get it

Comment: `len()` returns the length of the list. `range()` returns a list with the argument as the max. `reversed()` returns a reverse iterator of this list, yes, you guessed it, in reverse order.

Comment: If `n = len(list1)`, i iterates through the numbers `[(n-1), (n-2), ...0]`.  This is since reversed just iterates in the reverse direction i.e. range(n) would be `[0, ... n-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakdown of the line:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(list1)))
```

Suppose that `list1 = [1, 2, 3]`.

Then `len(list1) = 3` and the `range` will generate numbers from `0` to `2`.

`reversed` flips the order, into the numbers `2`, `1`, `0`,
and to print them from the range_iterator object,
you need to iterate over it which is what the for-loop does:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(list1))):
    print(i)
```

Results in:

```
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the comments to make them readable:

```py
def combie_lists(list1, list2):
      new_list = list2  #define a new list with the elements of list 2
      for i in reversed(range(len(list1))): #takes the numbers 0,1,2,3,... to len(list1) in reverse
        new_list.append(list1[i]) #add the element in list1 with the corresponding index
      return new_list #return the new list
```

BTW you can do it like that:

```py
combie_lists= lambda l1, l2: l2 + l1[::-1]
```